# Resize, crop and add a border to an image in CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to transform an image only with css, in this way :

1. Scale down image to 35px*35px
2. Crop it to remove unwanted borders (by 20%)
3. Add a css solid border

I've managed to make something that kind of work but it seems to be an overkill, is there any simple and elegant solution ?

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid rgb(163,53,238); width:25px;height: 25px;"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTp2a.png" width=42 height=42 style="clip-path: polygon(20% 20%,80% 20%,80% 80%,20% 80%);margin:-8.4px"></div>
```

edit: Input image will always be squarish

Comment: overflow hidden on the container instead of clip-path

Answer (score 1):

You can update the width of both elements.

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid rgb(163,53,238); width:35px;height: 35px;"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTp2a.png" width=52 height=52 style="clip-path: polygon(20% 20%,80% 20%,80% 80%,20% 80%);margin:-8.4px"></div>
```

Comment: It looks good but there is a margin between the border and the cropped image in your example, ideally there should be no gap.